# Grab Information From SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Right now I have made a SQL database with some information in them.

I currently have three tables with the following columns:

> (1) table name = senators; columns = Dnumber, Name
>   (2) table name = committees; columns = ID, Committee 
>   (3) table name = memberCommittee; columns = ID, Dnumber

My select statement:

> SELECT DISTINCT s.name as Senator FROM senators as s, committees as
>   c, memberCommittee as m WHERE s.Dnumber = m.Dnumber and c.ID = m.ID
>   and c.ID = "1001";

The goal of this is to grab the information using the three tables and show the "Name" that's in ID "1001". My select statement works as it will show the people in the committee with the ID of 1001, but I don't quite understand the PHP part of getting the information.

This part:

*

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT s.name as Senator 
     FROM senators as s, committees as c, memberCommittee as m 
    WHERE s.Dnumber =m.Dnumber and c.ID = m.ID and c.ID = "1001");  

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            unset($id, $Senator);           
            //$id = $row['Features'];   
            $Senator = $row['Senator'];
            echo '<option value="'.$Senator.'">'.$Senator.'</option>';      

    }
```

*

Could someone help me with it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
     document.getElementById('senator').className = listindex;
   </script>
   
   <style>
   optgroup {
     display: none;
   }

   select.Agriculture 
   optgroup.Agriculture
   {
     display: block;
   }
   
   div#header{
   padding: 1px;
   color: yellow;
   padding-left: 9px;
   background-color: #000080;
   }
   
   .category_div{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .sub_category_div{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .microphone{
   padding: 3px;
   }
   
   .body{
   padding-right: 5px;
   }
   </style>
 </head>
 
<body>

 <div class="header" id="header">
 <h1>Indiana State Senate IT</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="room130">
 <h3>Room 130</h3>
 <form target="Room 130" action = "room130.php" method="POST">
  <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Committee:
   <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Select Committee</option>
    <option value="Agriculture">AGRICULTURE</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
  Individual:
   <select name="senator" id="senator">
    <option value="">Select individual</option>
     <optgroup class="Agriculture">
      <?php
       $conn = mysqli_connect("db.soic.indiana.edu", "i308f16_team43", "my+sql=i308f16_team43", "i308f16_team43");

       if(!$conn){
         die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error());
       }
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT s.name as Senator FROM senators as s, committees as c, memberCommittee as m WHERE s.Dnumber = m.Dnumber and c.ID = m.ID and c.ID = "1001");
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           unset($id, $Senator);
           //$id = $row['Features'];
           $Senator = $row['Senator'];
           echo '<option value="'.$Senator.'">'.$Senator.'</option>';
         }
       ?>         
     </optgroup>
    </option>
   </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this line `$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT s.name as Senator FROM senators as s, committees as c, memberCommittee as m WHERE s.Dnumber = m.Dnumber and c.ID = m.ID and c.ID = "1001");` lack --> "  use this `$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT s.name as Senator FROM senators as s, committees as c, memberCommittee as m WHERE s.Dnumber = m.Dnumber and c.ID = m.ID and c.ID = '1001' ")`  Single quote in your where

Comment: @GuillermoAndresFuentesMoral changed it...Not sure what the variable means in the "While" statement

Comment: Your print_r variable `$row` ? show result?

Comment: @GuillermoAndresFuentesMoral no it's not grabbing the results from my SQL tables

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong double quotes sequence (you should wrap the 1001 inside single quote

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT s.name as Senator 
     FROM senators as s, committees as c, memberCommittee as m 
    WHERE s.Dnumber =m.Dnumber and c.ID = m.ID and c.ID = '1001'");
```

and You should echo  the rows result

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row['Senator'].'">'. $row['Senator'] .'</option>';
```

and be sure you have not c.ID as integer  in this case you should use   1001 withou single quotes

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT 
                            s.name as Senator 
                          FROM senators as s
                            , committees as c
                            , memberCommittee as m 
                          WHERE s.Dnumber =m.Dnumber 
                          and c.ID = m.ID 
                          and c.ID = 1001;");
```

and (just a suggestion)  you should ise explicit join sintax )

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT 
                                s.name as Senator 
                              FROM senators as s
                              INNER  JOIN memberCommittee as m on s.Dnumber =m.Dnumber 
                              INNER JOIN  committees as c on  and c.ID = m.ID 
                              WHERE c.ID = 1001");
```

Comment: I made the correct fixes and it's not picking up. I'm assuming my variables are incorrect? If it is can you assist me?

Comment: to understand at what point you are .. from your code gets a list of options with the wrong value, or you get no value for options ?.. in other words, your select gives you some result or not?

Comment: I'm not getting any results at all. My select statement works, so it must be getting the variables correctly in the "while part".

Comment: how you say  "My select statement works"   if not run the while for rows?

Comment: And which  data type is the column  c.ID ??

Comment: I tested my select statement in putty and it showed the correct names. So I have two tables, one is just the names and their ID and one is committee and their ID. I combined the two ID in the third table so I can call information. Right now I want all the Names (in table: senators) that are currently in (C.ID = "1001").

Comment: Anyway i have added  some brief suggestion

Comment: Thanks, but that part is correct. It's the next part that I believe is incorrect.

Comment: if you think that the sql part is right then  the while must run (eventually showing  wrong data  but run )

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query() returns a mysqli_result object (of false on failure). This object has a method called ::fetch_assoc() (or fetch_assoc(), procedural style) which takes no arguments and returns an array. While is used to iterate until all rows returned (one at a time) to the $row variable. When $row gets false from fetch_assoc() the loop stops.
Check the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php